# Python, killing a process does not kill its child daemon processes

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, kill-process

I have a system implemented in Python, with a main script, launcher.py, that I use to create and run a bunch of inter-communicating child processes.

***launcher.py***

```
def main():

    set_start_method("spawn")
    ev_killing_switch = mp.Event()

    ## -----------------------
    ## multiprocessing 
    ## -----------------------
    ## child_01
    child_01 = mp.Process(target=Child_01_Initializer, args=(...), daemon=True)
    child_01.start()

    ## child_02
    child_02 = mp.Process(target=Child_02_Initializer, args=(ev_killing_switch, ...), daemon=True)
    child_02.start()

    ## child_03
    child_03 = mp.Process(target=Child_03_Initializer, args=(...), daemon=True)
    child_03.start()

    ## child_04
    child_04 = mp.Process(target=Child_04_Initializer, args=(...), daemon=True)
    child_04.start()


    ev_killing_switch.wait()
    print("System stopped, terminating all processes.")
    sys.exit(0)
```

I have an Event that can be set in one of the child processes, and at that point the main process is terminated, and all the children daemon processes are closed as well.

However, I need to terminate the main process (and, consequently, the children) externally, by using a shell script. I tried retrieving the PID of the main process and killing it, but in this way no cleanup function is called by the main process, which leaves its children running.
How can I fix this? An idea would be to retrieve the PIDs of the children as well and kill them, is there another possibility?

Comment: If you want to kill the child processes when the parent exits, why do you make them daemons in the first place?

Comment: Like Homer512 said, it seems those threads should not be daemons if you want them to be attached to the main thread on exit.

Comment: According to multiprocess daemon documentation (https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.daemon), "When a process exits, it attempts to terminate all of its daemonic child processes". So, by setting daemon=True, when launcher ends it will kill all the subprocesses, as long as it ends gracefully, and is not killed by an external script, which is what I'm doing. Or am I misunderstanding it? I tried switching daemon to False for the children processes, but this way the children stay running even after launcher ends normally.